# Does the network learn based on previous training or does it restart? Matlab, neuralnetworks

Tags: neural-network, matlab

In Matlab, if you build a simple network and train it:

```
OP = feedforwardnet(5, 'traingdm');
inputsVals = [0,1,2,3,4];
targetVals = [3,2,5,1,9];
OP = train(OP,inputsVals,targetVals);
```

then you train it again so another `OP = train(OP,inputsVals,targetVals);`

What is happens to the network? Does it train again based on what it learned the first time you did `OP = train(OP,inputsVals,targetVals);` or does it train as if it were the first time training the network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It trains again based on what it learned the first time you did `OP = train(OP,inputsVals,targetVals)`. More generally, `train` uses your network's weights, i.e. it does not initialize the weights. The weight initialization happens in `feedforwardnet`.

Example:

```
% To generate reproducible results 
% http://stackoverflow.com/a/7797635/395857
rng(1234,'twister')

% Prepare input and target vectors
[x,t] = simplefit_dataset;

% Create ANN
net = feedforwardnet(10);

% Loop to see where train() initializes the weights
for i = 1:10

    % Learn
    net.trainParam.epochs = 1;
    net = train(net,x,t);

    % Score
    y = net(x);
    perf = perform(net,y,t)
end
```

yields

```
perf =

    0.4825


perf =

    0.0093


perf =

    0.0034


perf =

    0.0034


perf =

    0.0034


perf =

    0.0034


perf =

    0.0034


perf =

    0.0034


perf =

    0.0034


perf =

    0.0028
```